What is the recommended way to deploy a self hosted instance of safe-core to AWS?

What is the recommended way to deploy a self hosted instance to AWS? I see the docker compose file is there in the Repo but AWS Copilot CLI doesn't support that anymore and the k8s charts seem to be incomplete so seems like we would have to split it out into a bunch of different task definitions.

This is for an L2 and custom chain. Do we need to submit a PR to add the chain to any of the other repos? I see theres chain IDs in here the gnosis_safe_l2.json file

In what circumstances would all components need to be installed for self hosting vs. just the safe-transaction-service



Thanks for your great questions.
Does our Safe{Core} Infrastructure deployment guide help in this regard?
If yes, please mark this question answered. If no, please let me know in the comments, and I will help you out.

No it does not, AWS no longer supports docker compose so it looks like we would have to attempt to split each service out into a task definition and make sure networking also works the same in AWS. The kubernetes charts also appear to be incomplete.
